# Converting Web Page with Google map into PDF

Tags: google-maps, itext, html

I am using iTextSharp library for converting my .aspx page into PDF. I am using Table, labels and Google map in my page. Every thing converts into PDF except Google map. In PDF file it shows Google map code instead of showing Map. I could not understand, how to fix this problem ?

Any help to fix this

Comment: Could you use Google's static maps?  Since static maps are images they  might render into PDF.  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index.html#quick_example

Answer (score 0):

So you're using iTextSharp to parse HTML, right? Unfortunately iText and iTextSharp's HTML parsers are still in their infancy and Google's maps use both iframes and JavaScript, neither of which are supported in the parser. You can see a [list of supported HTML tags here](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/simpleparser/HTMLTagProcessors.cs?revision=284&view=markup#l59). I would not be surprised if adding a JavaScript interpreter is not even on the to-do list.